# SCSS variable not taking effect

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I am currently struggling to understand why my changes to the system colors aren't taking effect.

This is the image I am seeing in chrome.

[image: This is the image I am seeing in chrome.]

However this is what I expect to see

[image: However this is what I expect to see]

I have three files variables.scss, the bootstrap.scss and a branding.scss.
This is my import list in the main styles.scss within my angular project.

This is my import list.

```
@import "styles/variables";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "styles/branding";
```

A snippet of my variables

```
/* =====================================
    General Colours
===================================== */

$color-black: rgb(0,0,0);
$color-white: rgb(255,255,255);

/* System Backgrounds
===================================== */
$color-lm-bg-primary:   #8E8E93;
$color-lm-bg-secondary: #8E8E93;
$color-lm-bg-tertiary:  #8E8E93;

/* System Greys
===================================== */
$color-lm-grey-1:   #8E8E93;
$color-lm-grey-2:   #AEAEB2;
$color-lm-grey-3:   #C7C7CC;
$color-lm-grey-4:   #D1D1D6;
$color-lm-grey-5:   #E5E5EA;
$color-lm-grey-6:   #F2F2F7;

/* System Tints
===================================== */
$color-lm-blue:     #007AFF;
$color-lm-green:    #34C759;
$color-lm-indigo:   #5856D6;
```

Finally here is my branding.scss

```
:root {

    /* General backgrounds and colours
    ===================================== */
    --bg-primary-color:     $color-lm-bg-primary;
    --bg-secondary-color:   $color-lm-bg-secondary;
    --bg-tertiary-color:    $color-lm-bg-tertiary;
    --text-color:           $color-black;

    /* General backgrounds and colours
    ===================================== */
    --button-primary-bg:        $color-lm-blue;
    --button-secondary-bg:      $color-white;
    --button-green-bg:          $color-lm-green;
    --button-red-bg:            $color-lm-red;

    --button-primary-color:     $color-white;
    --button-secondary-color:   $color-lm-blue;
    --button-green-color:       $color-white;
    --button-red-color:         $color-white;
}

html,
body {
        background-color: var(--bg-primary-color);
        color: var(--color-text);
}

/* Button Classes
===================================== */
body .btn-primary-theme {
  background-color: var(--button-primary-bg);
  color: var(--button-primary-color);
}
```

I really don't understand why it's not taking effect I can't see anything obvious to further compound the issue chrome's developer tools show the following.

This image is the button class

[image]

And this one is bootstraps colors.

[image]

The intention in the future is to add a light and dark theme but that's for another time.

Any help will be graciously appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a special syntax for your purpose: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/css-vars

```
$accent-color: #fbbc04;

:root {
  // WRONG, will not work in recent Sass versions.
  --accent-color-wrong: $accent-color;

  // RIGHT, will work in all Sass versions.
  --accent-color-right: #{$accent-color};
}
```

You will need to wrap your SCSS variables like `#{$color}` to be transpiled correctly.